# Translation of : The disjunction of two contingencies can be a tautology.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers, predicate-logic

The statement is: "The disjunction of two contingencies can be a tautology."
The predicates are: 
$C(x)$: "$x$ is a contradiction."
$T(x)$: "$x$ is a tautology."

The book says the answer is 
$$\exists{x}\exists{y}(\lnot T(x) \wedge \lnot C(x) \wedge \lnot T(y) \wedge \lnot C(y) \wedge T(x\lor y)) $$
However, I was thinking something more along the lines of
$$\exists{x}\exists{y}(\lnot T(x) \wedge \lnot C(x) \wedge \lnot T(y) \wedge \lnot C(y) \rightarrow T(x\lor y)) $$

What's wrong with my line of thinking?

Comment: thiefjack: Please check my edit: I assumed there was a typo in your second expression where, immediately before $C(y)$ you had $\land \land C(y)...$, and I assume you meant $\land \lnot C(y)...$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

Comment: Would you like another answer? Or do you now understand why to two are not equivalent? (or why your expression doesn't express the statement you need to express).

Comment: I understand now and have accepted Fernandez's response. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, thiefjack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book's answer says "There exist $x,y$ such that both are neither tautologies nor contradictions, and their disjunction is a tautology", which is exactly what the sentence says.

Your answer says (assuming you meant to put parentheses around the entire part before '$\to$') "There exist $x,y$ such that the fact that both are neither tautologies nor contradictions implies that their disjunction is a tautology".

This is problematic, since $F\to T$ and $F\to T$ both hold, if, for example, $x$ is a tautology, the part on the left of '$\to$' is false and thus $x,y$ satisfy the predicate and the entire predicate may be true even though $x$ is not a contingency, which means that, for example, in a model containing only one contingency and some tautologies, the truth value of the predicate would change.

Answer (score 2):

Which book is in question??? On the face of it, the suggested answer is simply ill-formed. Propositional connectives like $\lor$ connect *propositions* not terms, so in standard first-order syntax $T(x \lor  y)$  is *not* a well-formed formula.

Comment: It seems to be using T and C as functions on propositions.

Comment: The book’s answer is not ill-formed: $T$ and $C$ take propositions as arguments. The OP’s answer *is* ill-formed, though the double conjunction may be a typo for $\land\neg$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott As I said, *on the face of it*, the book's answer is ill-formed. Sure, you *can* take the first-order variables to be running over propositions-as-objects, and introduce a function $\overline{\lor}$ that applies to two denoting terms to form a term alongside the familiar truth-function $\lor$ which applies to two sentences to form a sentence. But this is quite sophisticated stuff (and it would be naughty to use the same undecorated symbol for the two different categories of function $\lor$ vs. $\overline{\lor}$): so which book does it???

Comment: But I disagree: *on the face of it* the book’s answer makes perfectly good sense, given the wording of the question. It’s only from a more sophisticated point of view that it becomes problematic. And yes, it *does* become problematic, but not in a way that’s likely to cause trouble in a sophomore-level discrete math course in section whose purpose is to introduce students to basic logical notation, nothing more. And that’s what this is: I was able to track down the question, and it’s from Kenneth H. Rosen’s widely used *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*.

Comment: Thanks for the detective work, @BrianM.Scott! Interesting. Rosen's book really does seem to confuse *expressing* a proposition with *denoting* a proposition. (The Wittgenstein of the *Tractatus* is spinning in his grave ...)